# reject nil values while appending to ruby array inside loop

Tags: ruby

I have a loop inside which I am appending the result of the loop to an array. The code is like this

```
urls = []
series_id = [100,200,300,400]
series_id.each do |id|
  result_urls += iterate_id_and_get_urls(id)
end

def iterate_id_and_get_urls(id)
  #do something with id and maps it and returns its url which would result in an array
  #return that url array
end
```

But iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) can also return nil sometimes which would result nil to be appended in result_urls. How can I avoid that. I am looking for something like the below

```
result_urls += iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) unless nil?
```

Comment: result_urls += iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) unless iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) = nil

Comment: You can do result_urls.compact at the end which will remove all nil values

Comment: @HetalKhunti I can do like this result_urls += iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) unless iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) = nil. But that would make call to iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) twice, if I am not wrong..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
series_id.each do |id|
  if value = iterate_id_and_get_urls(id)
    result_urls += value.compact
  end
end
```

So `nil` url's will not get added to `result_urls`

**[Compact](http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/compact)** : Returns a copy of `self` with all `nil` elements **removed**.

Comment: use `unless` instead of `if !`

Comment: And also, is the conditional necessary at all if you use `#compact`?

Comment: #compact removes nil and returns empty array. In ruby [] is also evaluated as true. so #empty? returns true or false. based on that value gets appended to result_urls

Comment: Yes, but I suspect that if you drop it, the code will work anyway =)

Comment: You mean if !value.empty?.If so, then it wont work as [nil].empty? returns false and condition passes

Comment: Simple statement `result_urls += value.compact` will work, to be completely clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65287/discussion-between-kranthi-and-boris-stitnicky).

Answer (score 3):

How about using [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map):

```
result_urls = series_id.flat_map { |id| iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) }.compact
```

or even:

```
result_urls = series_id.flat_map { |id| iterate_id_and_get_urls(id) || [] }
```

Comment: When I heard about `flat_map`, I thought to myself, this is like `flatten`, cool but not much use for it. You found a good usecase here, congrats.

Answer (score 1):

```
series_id.map( &method( :iterate_id_and_get_urls ) ).compact.reduce( [], :+ ).compact
```